# Drawing on canvas in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, html5-canvas

So I have been having this problem with HTML5 canvas and Bootstrap. Esentially, I inserted a canvas inside a Bootstrap template (put it in an element with the class of "jumbotron"). And I want to be able to draw inside that canvas using my mouse. But, my mouse position and the editable-canvas area seem off. I took a snap-shot (hope I uploaded it correctly), the canvas is the pale-yellow thing with the purple border and the actual mouse position is the arrow I drew with blue, the blue dot is where the page sees the mouse position and begins drawing the line. Also, it won`t let me use the whole canvas area, I can only draw in the green square I outlined in the photo...

HTML code:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
        <canvas id="draw" width="800" height="800"></canvas>
 </div>
```

JS code to activate the drawing:

```
function draw(e) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(lastX, lastY);
        ctx.lineTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
        ctx.stroke();
        [lastX, lastY] = [e.offsetX, e.offsetY];
}
```

I also have to add that if I get the canvas into a new HTML (without Bootstrap), the code works perfectly (dot/line is following the mouse cursor fine). Also, if I delete the class "jumbotron", the mouse Position will be read correctly. I tried looking into the styles for "jumbotron", digged it up, tried using BoundingRect and others, but I could not figure this one out.

I am new here, so take me slow :) Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because mouse position is relative to window. You must make some math to calculate coordinates relative to canvas. Some code for understanding

```
rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect()
x = e.offsetX - rect.x
y = e.offsetY - rect.y
```

Then use x, y to draw something on canvas.

Also you can check my example where I draw with mouse without some additional calculations.
https://codepen.io/Profesor08/pen/aYJWRZ

Comment: Thanks! You saved me! Actually, I tried something similar to this, but it did not work for some reason.... But now, after a break, refreshed brains and your help, everything has solved. Thanks a lot :)